# Sorting python dict by value in Python 3.7

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, python-3.7, built-in

I have a dict like the following:

```
d = {"string0": 0, "string2": 2, "string1": 1}
```

I want to sort this by int values so that it would like:

```
d = {"string0": 0, "string1": 1, "string2": 2}
```

I know that I can sort lists with the help of built-in function `sorted()` specifying `key` argument with lambda function like the following:

```
sorted_d = {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])}
```

But for some reason it seems to not work, the dict remains as original.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @J'e, the accepted answer in that question looks like my tried solution which does not work for me.

Comment: @Anastaia are you expecting `d` to have changed? Your code works fine and the result in `sorted_d` looks like what you want.

Comment: @J'e, maybe that solution works only in Python 3.6, but does not work in Python 3.7?

Comment: @Anastaia the accepted answer is out of date but did you look at the other answers?

Comment: @Anastaia The code you provided in the question works fine for me (and yes, I tested it with Python 3.7)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can follow this answer

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/13968434)

or Use this:

```
d = {"string0": 0, "string2": 2, "string1": 1}
sorted_x = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
print(sorted_x)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "or Use this"? That exact code is in that answer, except you changed `x` to `d`, and I'm quite certain that's what you actually did, since you forgot to rename the `sorted_x` variable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is `1[1]` which is invalid Python. You want `i[1]`. That change will do it.